# How to move bookmarks *with icons* from Firefox to Safari

Tags: macos, safari, firefox

I dumped my old Dell for a new MacBook Pro. Firefox looks gawdawful on my retina display, so I'm trying Safari. I had 20+ bookmarks in FF's Bookmarks Toolbar. Each had it's own icon, either grabbed from the target domain or from a picture I had saved... so I was able to give each one a one or two character name, so I easily could see them and select the ones I wanted. Upon the import, Safari ditched the icons.

1. Is there any way to move bookmarks *with* icons from FFx to Safari?
2. Is there any way to even *show* icons on the Safari toolbar?

Comment: How did you give custom icons to bookmarks in the first place?

Comment: Try using Chrome instead.

Answer (score 2):

Safari doesn't show icons for bookmarks *in the toolbar* itself, only in the bookmark menus.

The icons aren't stored with the bookmarks, Safari has a separate cache for all the favicons of sites that have been visited (I believe this is the case for Firefox and Chrome as well, but I'm not 100% sure). If you look in the bookmarks viewer or menu, open a site that doesn't have an icon, then check back in the bookmarks viewer, you'll see that Safari has added the icon to that bookmark entry (assuming the site has a favicon set in the first place). So while you may not see icons at first for bookmarks you import, they'll fill in eventually as you visit the sites.